# Clean up RAM (Maybe win32 api)?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, memory, ram

Every so often I see "Speed Up Your PC" programs that offer a RAM cleaning feature.

They claim to defrag and free up unused memory like a garbage collector or something... not sure.

Here are some examples:

http://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/Memory-Tweak/Clean-Ram.shtml

http://download.cnet.com/Instant-Memory-Cleaner/3000-2086_4-10571833.html

http://www.uniblue.com/software/speedupmypc/

I'm interested in learning about the Win32 C API's that they are using, if anyone has knowledge.

I've heard about the ProcessIdleTasks() in advapi32.dll trick, but doesn't look too legit looking at the documentation on that function.

Comment: If you want to clean up your RAM, just reboot the computer and complain to companies that make a process with an ongoing leak. Small optimizations on RAM shouldn't make too much of a difference in performance, but it could be a good project.

Comment: Allocate a big chunk of memory, almost as big as RAM, commit (touch) it, free it. Enjoy you empty memory and how all other programs struggle to get their memory back from the swap.

Comment: For reference, a discussion on the utility of such things on SuperUser: http://superuser.com/questions/214526/how-does-a-free-up-ram-utility-free-up-ram

Comment: I seriously doubt such programs accomplish anything useful at all.  The only use I can imagine for them would be as a band-aid for badly written programs.

Comment: All these apps do is muck with Windows' memory management which actually does a very good job on its own.

Comment: Most of them are probably scams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really insist on doing this, you could enumerate processes, open a handle to each, and call [`SetProcessWorkingSetSize(process_handle, -1, -1);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686234.aspx) for each (but you *really* don't want to do this).

Comment: gave it to you since it gave a win32 api to do what was asked (even though no1 shud)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how those particular programs work, but in the past I saw the source to a similar program.

It basically allocated a ton of RAM in one shot and then released it.

System RAM was "freed" because other programs had to swap to the disk.

Comment: @Naszta: And yet, probably the only one. I have had to deal with constant swapping, and it is NOT fun. That's when I quadrupled my RAM.